# Set a focus when scaling resizing background video in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey everyone I have been having some trouble figuring out how to focus a background video in html.
I have spent a lot of time to come up with virtually nothing so far
The code I have is

```
<style>
.videoContainer 
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.videoContainer video 
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;    
}
</style>

<div class="videoContainer">
    <video src="movie.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
</div>
```

I have been trying to figure out how to put the full screen video on the background and just have it scale with the focus on the center of the video as you resize the window like this website for example: http://urbaninfluence.com/

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED - This works. See my jsfiddle below...

Try adding the following styles to .videoContainer video

```css
.videoContainer 
{
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    border:solid 1px #f00;
}

.videoContainer video 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width:1920px;
    min-height:1080px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);/*For IE9*/
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
    <video src="http://video.blendertestbuilds.de/download.blender.org/peach/trailer_1080p.mov" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not fill the browser window like the linked example. Also, you can't have 2 `transform` properties, the second will override the first. You would need `transform:translate(-50%, -50%);`. [`-ms-transform` would be needed for IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Comment: It doesn't respond to the container size like `background-size: cover` would, and could use the standard non-webkit prefixes, but not too bad. +1

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure what you mean. If the container changes size the video will stay centered. I'm not real familiar with bg-size:cover though.

Comment: It stays centered and fills up to a 1920px/1080px, but the video does not scale down to cover the container showing more of the video. This would be the behavior of CSS `background-size: cover` for background images.